# Lambda inside orElseGet in bounded wildcard generics

Tags: java, generics, lambda, option-type

Part of my code looks like this:

```
EntityTypeEnum entityType = EntityTypeEnum.fromName(entityTypeName).orElseThrow(...);
EntityService<? extends AbstractEntityDto> entityService = entityServiceFactory.getEntityService(importType);

return getFooArgs(bar)
    .map(entityService::getListWithFooArgs)
    .orElseGet(()->entityService.getListNoArgs());
```

There is an **enum** by which I obtain service class using static method from **entityServiceFactory**. Then I invoke method **getFooArgs(...)**, that returns **Optional< FooArg >**. Then I'd like to map it using **EntityService** method or use a method without args to obtain "default" value, when **getFooArgs** return empty Optional.

```
public interface EntityService<T extends AbstractEntityDto> {
    List<T> getListNoArgs();
    List<T> getListWithFooArgs(FooArg fooArgs);
}
```

Sadly I get `Bad return type in lambda expression: List<capture of ? extends AbstractEntityDto> cannot be converted to List<capture of ? extends AbstractEntityDto>` from my IDE. What I have to do is:

```
Optional<List<? extends AbstractEntityDto>> listOptional = getFooArgs(bar)
        .map(entityService::getListWithFooArgs);

if(listOptional.isPresent())
    return listOptional.get();
else
    return entityService.getListNoArgs();
```

Can you explain why does it happen? I assume it's soemthing related to `?` and generics, but I thought that by using `?` a lot of type's restrictions would disappear.
If there is too little of code to figure it out, please let me know.

Comment: What is the return type of the enclosing method?

Comment: It's `List<? extends AbstractEntityDto>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not even try to find out why the compiler does not accept this construct. When it comes to type inference and wildcards, lots of things that look like they should work, don’t.

The easiest fix is to provide an explicit type for the generic invocation of `map`:

```
return getFooArgs(bar)
    .<List<? extends AbstractEntityDto>>map(entityService::getListWithFooArgs)
    .orElseGet(entityService::getListNoArgs);
```

Generally, you should [avoid wildcards in return types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/wildcardGuidelines.html). There is no value in carrying the wildcard around. In contrast, when you truly have code dealing with `List<ConcreteEntityDto>` and need to pass it to a method which should be able to deal with more cases, declaring a *parameter type* with a wildcard, like `List<? extends AbstractEntityDto>`, to accept the `List<ConcreteEntityDto>` and also `List<SomeOtherEntityDto>`, is quiet useful.

Note that given a

```
List<? extends AbstractEntityDto> list = …
```

you can do

```
List<AbstractEntityDto> view = Collections.unmodifiableList(list);
```

for subsequent processing which doesn’t attempt to modify the list. The wrapper returned by `unmodifiableList` prevents any attempt to insert elements into the list of unknown subtype of `AbstractEntityDto` but can guaranty to return instances of `AbstractEntityDto` for all query methods. That’s why this type change is valid.

Comment: *"Generally, you should avoid wildcards in return types."* ... this.

Comment: Thank you for an answer. Besides solving my issue, you provided some helpful informations. In that case, I feel like not retuing wildcards was not an option. I had to return `EntityService<? extends AbstractEntityDto>`, beucase  I implemented `EntityService` for every subclass of `AbstractEntityDto`. If static method returned `EntityService<AbstractEntityDto>` it would not be compatible with `EntityService<ConcreteEntityDto>`. Nevertheless, when it comes to collections, I agree with you.